# Prove $\| A^n\|^{1/n}$ converges to a finite positive limit, where $A$ is a square matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, matrix-norms

I'm stuck at the following problem:

Let $A$ be a non-nilpotent, real square matrix of dimension $n$ and define a matrix norm by $\| A \| = \sup_{\|x \| = 1} \|Ax\| $, where $ x\mapsto  \|x \| $ is a norm on $\mathbb R^n$. Prove that $ \| A^n\|^{1/n}$ converges to a finite positive limit.

What I have succeeded so far: I prove that $\lim_{n}\|A^n\|^{1/n} = \inf_{n \geq 1} \| A^n \|^{1/n}$, but I could not show $\|A^n\|^{1/n}$ is bounded away from 0 to make the infimum positive. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You are missing hypotheses, otherwise you can take $A$ to be the zero matrix, in which case your sequence is constant $0$.

Comment: I added the hypothesis, $A$ is non-nilpotent so it will not be zero after a finite number of iterations :)

Comment: Hint: $A$ being non-nilpotent means that is has some nonzero (complex) eigenvalue $\lambda$. Show that the limit is bounded below by $|\lambda|$. Actually, the limit is equal precisely to the largest absolute value of an eigenvalue of $A$, but this is nontrivial. (this is a special case of a more general theorem about Banach algebras)

Comment: Search the net for spectral radius formula.

Comment: Thank you all, I got the answer now :)